# Title bar buttons lose highlighted state when hovered in D7 on Win10

Tags: windows, delphi

When you place the mouse over a window's title bar buttons (minimize, maximize, close) in Windows 10, the button becomes highlighted in red color.

However, if you compile a program with Delphi 7, run it, and put the mouse over one of those buttons, the button only stays highlighted for a fraction of a second and then immediately returns to normal.

This also happens with a program that does nothing -- compile an empty form, run it, and the same thing happens...

Does anyone know what is going on, and how to make those buttons behave the standard way?

Comment: The same thing happens whether I include TXPManifest or not. My application supports visual styles. The same thing happens regardless of how simple (e.g. an empty form) or how complex (multiple forms, XP Manifest, etc) the program is.

Comment: Indeed, the issue is dealt with in detail there at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31630280/how-to-make-hovering-over-minimize-maximize-and-close-buttons-behave?rq=1