# How to hide main form rather than closing it?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

If the user clicks **X** on my main form, i want the form to hide, rather than close. This sounds like a job for the [**OnClose** form event](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_TForm_OnClose.html):

> Use OnClose to perform special processing when the form closes. The OnClose event specifies which event handler to call when a form is about to close. The handler specified by OnClose might, for example, test to make sure all fields in a data-entry form have valid contents before allowing the form to close.
>
> A form is closed by the Close method or when the user chooses Close from the form's system menu.
>
> The TCloseEvent type points to a method that handles the closing of a form. The value of the Action parameter determines if the form actually closes. These are the possible values of Action:
>
> - **caNone**: The form is not allowed to close, so nothing happens.
> - **caHide**: The form is not closed, but just hidden. Your application can still access a hidden form.
> - **caFree**: The form is closed and all allocated memory for the form is freed.
> - **caMinimize**: The form is minimized, rather than closed. This is the default action for MDI child forms.

Which i test in an empty application with one form:

```
procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
    Action := caHide;
end;
```

So now when i click **X**, (rather than hiding) the form closes and the application terminates:

[image]

...which sounds like a job for the **OnClose** event...

### Bonus Reading

**Vcl.Forms.pas**

```
procedure TCustomForm.Close;
var
   CloseAction: TCloseAction;
begin
   if fsModal in FFormState then
      ModalResult := mrCancel
   else if CloseQuery then
   begin
      if FormStyle = fsMDIChild then
         if biMinimize in BorderIcons then
            CloseAction := caMinimize 
         else
            CloseAction := caNone
      else
         CloseAction := caHide;

      DoClose(CloseAction);
      if CloseAction <> caNone then
      begin
         if Application.MainForm = Self then //Borland doesn't hate developers; it just hates me
            Application.Terminate
         else if CloseAction = caHide then   
            Hide
         else if CloseAction = caMinimize then 
            WindowState := wsMinimized
         else 
            Release;
      end;
   end;
end;
```

### Bonus Reading

- [How to make hovering over Minimize, Maximize, and Close buttons behave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31630280/how-to-make-hovering-over-minimize-maximize-and-close-buttons-behave)
- [Hide form instead of closing when close button clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021681/hide-form-instead-of-closing-when-close-button-clicked)
- [How to show a modal dialog from a modeless form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31705874/how-to-show-a-modal-dialog-from-a-modeless-form) *(Did Windows, WinForms, WPF, MessageBox, TaskDialog, ProgressDialog, SHFileOperation, IFileOperation all get it wrong? Nobody ever uses modeless windows?)*

Comment: Main form is different. Any secondary form will comply.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When the user closes a window, it receives a `WM_CLOSE` message, which triggers `TForm` to call its `Close()` method on itself.  Calling `Close()` on the project's `MainForm` *always* terminates the app, as this is hard-coded behavior in `TCustomForm.Close()`:

```
procedure TCustomForm.Close;
var
  CloseAction: TCloseAction;
begin
  if fsModal in FFormState then
    ModalResult := mrCancel
  else
    if CloseQuery then
    begin
      if FormStyle = fsMDIChild then
        if biMinimize in BorderIcons then
          CloseAction := caMinimize else
          CloseAction := caNone
      else
        CloseAction := caHide;
      DoClose(CloseAction);
      if CloseAction <> caNone then
        if Application.MainForm = Self then Application.Terminate // <-- HERE
        else if CloseAction = caHide then Hide
        else if CloseAction = caMinimize then WindowState := wsMinimized
        else Release;
    end;
end;
```

Only secondary `TForm` objects respect the output of the `OnClose` handler.

To do what you are asking for, you can either:

- handle `WM_CLOSE` directly and skip `Close()`.

  ```
  private
    procedure WMClose(var Message: TMessage); message WM_CLOSE;

  procedure TForm1.WMClose(var Message: TMessage);
  begin
    Hide;
    // DO NOT call inherited ...
  end;
  ```
- have your MainForm's `OnClose` handler call `Hide()` directly and return `caNone`:

  ```
  procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  begin
    Hide;
    Action := caNone;
  end;
  ```

Answer (score 8):

Try the `OnCloseQuery` event.  Hide the form and set `CanClose` to False. You should be good.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
  Hide;
  CanClose := False;
end;
```